Unable to inline JS and CSS using webpack
I have been dealing with this problem for past 2 days and couldn't resolve it. I tried few other steps posted in stackoverflow but couldn't make it work and all the questions were 3-4 years old as well.
I have a build folder containing - bundle.js, bundle.css and index.html. The index.html contains <link href="bundle.css"> and <script src="bundle.js">.
I am trying to inline the bundle.js and bundle.css into index.html using webpack. I am facing two problems:

JS file gets inlined but the index.html still has script src="bundle.js"
CSS does not get inlined at all and neither does it appear in dist folder

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>

    <title>Internal site</title>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='bundle.css'>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require('html-inline-css-webpack-plugin').default;
const HtmlInlineScriptWebpackPlugin = require('html-inline-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './internal_site/public/'),
    entry: {
        main: './bundle.js', // Entry JavaScript file
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js', // Output JS bundle
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Output directory
        clean: true, // Clean output directory before build
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/, // Match CSS files
                use: [
                    'style-loader', // Extract CSS into separate files
                    'css-loader', // Resolve CSS imports
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html', // Path to your index.html
            inject: 'body', // Inject scripts into the body

            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true, // Minify HTML
                removeComments: true, // Remove comments
            },
        }),
        new HtmlInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(), // Inline CSS into <style> tags
        new HtmlInlineScriptWebpackPlugin(), // Inline JavaScript into <script> tags
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new (require('terser-webpack-plugin'))({
                extractComments: false, // Remove comments
            }),
        ],
    },
    mode: 'production',
};

Versions:
"webpack": "^5.97.1",
"webpack-cli": "^6.0.1"



You specified mode: 'production'. Is it a production-only issue, or does it happen also in dev mode? 2. Try enabling more verbose logging: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/


Тo easily inline JS and CSS into HTML you can use the html-bundler-webpack-plugin.
Using this plugin your source JS and SCSS/CSS files should be defined directly in HTML.
If you import CSS in JS, then in HTML should be defined only source JS file.
For example, there is your source JS file ./bundle.js:
import './style.css';

console.log('>> bundle');

Place the script tag in HTML where you want, in the head or in the body.
Exactly at the same place will be inlined JS in generated HTML.
You don't need to define the JS file in Webpack entry.
The plugin resolves the source JS file in HTML automatically.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Internal site</title>
    <!-- path to source CSS file relative to this HTML file -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./bundle.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <!-- path to source JS file relative to this HTML file -->
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './internal_site/public/'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Output directory
        clean: true, // Clean output directory before build
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/, // Match CSS files
                use: [
                    'css-loader', // Resolve CSS imports
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
          entry: {
            index: './index.html', // Path to your index.html
          },
          js: {
            // output filename of compiled JavaScript, used if inline is false
            filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js',
            inline: true, // Inline JavaScript into <script> tags
          },
          css: {
            // output filename of extracted CSS, used if inline is false
            filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].css',
            inline: true, // Inline CSS into <style> tags
          },
          minify: true, // Enable minify HTML
          minifyOptions: {
            collapseWhitespace: true, // Minify HTML
            removeComments: true, // Remove comments
          },
        }),
    ],
    mode: 'production',
};

All source SCSS/CSS and JS files will be processed via Webpack and the compiled CSS and JS will be inlined into HTML.
The generated HTML will contains inlined CSS and JS:
dist/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Internal site</title>
    <!-- inlined CSS from bundle.css -->
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- inlined CSS from style.css imported in bundle.js -->
    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <!-- inlined JS -->
  <script>
    (() => {
      'use strict';
      console.log('>> bundle');
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>

The Bundler Plugin avoid extraction of comments, so you don't need the terser-webpack-plugin.
The Bundler Plugin replaces functionality of the plugins and loaders:

html-webpack-plugin
html-inline-css-webpack-plugin
html-inline-script-webpack-plugin
style-loader
and many other plugins and loaders

You can see additional information here:

How to inline CSS in HTML
How to inline JS in HTML
How to inline all resources into single HTML file

P.S.
you can create a small repo on GitHub and I can help you configure your project.
